# rent a car, rent out a car, hire a car

Tags: british-english

English not my native language.
I'm trying to understand what would be correct in British English.

If I want to use a car for some time. I can say, "I want to rent a car". But from my knowledge there may be a  misunderstanding. I can say the same words if I want to give a car to someone to use for some time and I want to receive payment.

So what would be correct and not misunderstanding?

- 1) I want to use a car for some time = "I want to hire a car"
- 2) I want to give a car to someone to use for some time = "rent out a car"

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This should probably be migrated to [ell.se], a perfect place for a question like this one. You might want to create a Stack Exchange account there, too.

Comment: Related (possible dupe): [The correct way to say something is hired on an hourly basis](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/69166/8019)

Comment: Do you really mean to use *rent* which implies a payment for temporary use? OR do you simply mean to *borrow* a car or *lend* a car which is something that might occur between family or friends?

Comment: Yes, I mean temporary to use a car and person that uses a car, pays for the usage. Regarding `hire`. I searched google `hire a car in uk` and there are many pages with title like hire a car in uk...

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As Jason points out, this is only correct for American English.

Hiring is normally something you do to a person. If you say that you're hiring a car, it sounds like you're hiring a driver who has a car.

Your use of "rent out" is correct if the person who borrows the car is paying you. You can use "loan out" if there's no payment.

Comment: In American English this is the case, but in British English, hiring a car is the idiomatically correct way to express this, if I'm not mistaken.  Google finds both phrases, but the car you pick up is called a "hire car" almost exclusively, rather than a rental car, so I'm wondering if renting a car is an introduced Americanism in the UK.  Hopefully a native BrE speaker can weigh in.

Comment: Even more clear is "rent out my car" or "rent out one of my cars",  because there is no way you can borrow a car that already belongs to you.